# Different request headers per environment

Tags: postman

I'm using the environments feature of postman but one environment needs to NOT have one of the request headers. Typically it would be harmless to send the additional unnecessary request header, but in my unique case it actually breaks the request, causing the endpoint to return a 401.

[Postman Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1m76.png)
(click link; sorry I don't have 10 rep yet to post an inline image)

Lets say I have a "Dev" environment and a "Prod" environment. When I choose Dev from the environments dropdown, I want the "need-me-for-dev-only" key and value. But when I choose Prod, I don't want that key/value sent in the request at all.

This can of course be achieved by unchecking that header item. However then I have to both switch environments and remember to check or uncheck the header as needed.

I tried setting a blank value for the variable (in Prod in this example) but having a key with no value causes an invalid header.

```
Accept: application/json
need-me-for-dev-only:
```

I tried just not having that environment variable for Prod, but then it literally sends the variable name including the handlebars

```
Accept: application/json
need-me-for-dev-only: {{dev-environment-variable}}
```

in the header (captured in fiddler).

Is it possible without scripting to have per-environment request headers? If not I will investigate scripting as a solution to my issue.

Comment: Scripting will probably be your best bet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612238/postman-get-the-environment-name-as-a-variable#58655480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this with Postman, using pre-request scripts and a little trick.

First of all, ensure your Dev environment has an "Environment" variable, and set it to "dev".

Now, for your request, in the `Pre-request Script`, add something like this:

```
let environment_name = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("Environment"); 

if(environment_name === "dev"){
    postman.setGlobalVariable("need-me-for-dev-only-key", "need-me-for-dev-only"); 
    postman.setGlobalVariable("need-me-for-dev-only-value", "your_value"); 
} else {
    postman.setGlobalVariable("need-me-for-dev-only-key", "something_else"); 
    postman.setGlobalVariable("need-me-for-dev-only-value", "something_else");
}
```

Basically, your setting your header key-value pairs depending on the environment. If it's "dev", we're setting the `need-me-for-dev-only` header. Otherwise, we will set arbitrary headers that will ultimately be ignored by your API.

Now, on the `Headers` sections of the request, you can add the following:

```
Accept: application/json
{{need-me-for-dev-only-key}}: {{need-me-for-dev-only-value}}
```

That's it.

Hope it made sense.

Comment: I see..yes it could solve my problem to use a variable for the header name, and make it a nonsensical string ("something_else") when Prod. But I would simplify your solution by setting the variables {{need-me-for-dev-only-key}} and {{need-me-for-dev-only-value}} directly within the environment variables instead of setting them in a script. For a scripting solution, I was hoping to find something like if not dev, postman.deleteResponseHeader('need-me-for-dev-only'). But I don't see any such function in the api.

Comment: Absolutely, you can certainly set it directly as Environment Variable without script, if further manipulation is not necessary. I don't think there's currently a way to remove headers through scripts. As an alternative, you can form the entire request within the script and decide what goes in the headers and body. The drawback though is that it over complicates your requests. If your calls are relatively simple, it's probably more straightforward to add the 'dummy' authorization value as above.

Comment: Newer versions of the Postman API/libs can directly inject headers, and there is a collection-level Pre-request Script tab. `pm.request.headers.add({ key: 'x-env-name', value: pm.environment.name })`

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I needed to do something similar, and have an alternative (thanks to the solution already provided).  When testing locally, I need a header, but don't need it for any other environments.  In each environment, I defined 2 variables; the key and the value.  In all environments but local, I left the values of each variable empty.  In local, I populated them as needed.  Then in the request, I reference the key and value variables from the environment.  That way it's in the environment, not a script in the collection or request.  As a bonus, you can set a preset, so when you encounter a request that doesn't have it, click the preset. This works in Version 9.0.8.

Comment: Please more precisely refer to "the solution already provided" by using the link provided by the "Share" button beneath it.