# Postman get the environment name as a variable

Tags: postman

I would like to know if it's possible to get the environment name as an environment variable in Postman.

Currently I'm setting it myself manually in the environment variables for each environment but it that can be retrieved from some sort of application variable that would be great.

I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you the name of the environment that's currently selected:

`pm.environment.set("envName", pm.environment.name)`

[image: Postman]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a doc page for the pm namespace?

Comment: This is the sandbox ref page - https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/ The docs are getting updated at the moment so there will be gaps but this will all be sorted very soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code snippet. This code will return you the environment name which is currently being used by POSTMAN.

```
console.info(pm.environment.name);
pm.environment.set("currentEnvName",pm.environment.name);
var environementName = pm.environment.get("currentEnvName");
console.log("Environement Name Current Used Is : "+environementName);
```